# Equivalent of "What would you do in my shoes" in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

How would you state it? Are there alternatives?

If the expression does exist, where does it come from?

Comment: Its another meaning but a similar picture: [In jemandes Fußstapfen treten](http://www.wissen.de/redewendung/jemandes-fussstapfen-treten-2013-01-18) means to follow in somebodies foot prints - meaning to be a follower.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't translate that figurative expression **directly**, word by word, into german. But in german, there's a similar expression with (IMHO) identical meaning:

> Was würden Sie **an meiner Stelle** tun?
>
> Was würdest Du **an meiner Stelle** tun?

It's a shortened form of

> Was würden Sie tun, wenn Sie an meiner Stelle wären?

Comment: Note that there is also a direct translation for the German one: "What would you do in my place?" So there are (at least) two English expressions that correspond to (at least) one German expression.

Answer (score 3):

My choice of a German translation for *"to be [walk, fit?] in someone's shoes"* is *"in jemandes Haut stecken"*. It preserves more of the idiomatic character of the original as opposed to *"an jemandes Stelle sein"*.

But I think that *"in someone's shoes"* is more neutral: *"In jemandes Haut stecken"* is used mainly in a context, where the described situation would be at least a nuisance. *"Stecken"* in its intransitive form is very similar to *"to stick"*.

Comment: I think "in jemandes Haut stecken" is about what someone *experiences* (that is, it's about empathy), while "an jemandes Stelle" refers more to his *situation* (and the options one has). Especially it sounds *very* wrong to me to say "Wenn ich in seiner Haut stecken würde, würde ich ...".